# Gzipped file arrives unzipped

Tags: arch-linux, wget, curl

I've recently set up an ArchLinux system at work and added the [ArchHaskell repo](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Haskell_package_guidelines#.5Bhaskell-core.5D).  This is far from the first time I do this.  I have a number of systems where it's worked just fine, but this last time it did not.  The signed repo database file, which is a gzipped tar-ball on the server, arrives as a straight tar-ball on my system.  This of course prevents `pacman`'s signature checking.

The strange this is that the other repo databases, e.g. `[core]`, do arrive gzipped just like they should!

I've tried downloading the same file using `wget` and `curl -O`, in both cases the file also arrives un-gzipped!

As far as I can judge the only difference between my machines where I don't have this behaviour, and the one where I do, is that they are on different networks (i.e. at home vs. at work).  I haven't had a chance to move the work system onto a different network yet, but I thought I'd ask this question even before doing that.

What on earth could explain this strange behaviour?

1. On my work system this one, out of 4, `pacman` repo databases arrives un-gzipped.
2. It arrives un-gzipped when using `wget` and `curl -O` manually.
3. It does not arrive un-gzipped on ArchLinux systems on other networks.

Comment: Check your aliases first; otherwise, `strace` your `wget` or `curl` call and see what's doing the gunzip.

Comment: I've done all the downloading as `root`, and I have no aliases in `root`'s config at all, so unfortunately that doesn't explain it.

Comment: I've now done an `strace` of `curl -O`, and there seems to be nothing on the client machine doing the un-gzipping, i.e. the output of `strace` doesn't contain any mention of 'zip'.  The same is true when using `ltrace`.  I'm leaning towards the network doing something strange, would that be possible?